# Setting systemd.unit variables from file

Tags: systemd

I'm looking for a way to set systemd (.service, .unit, ...) variable (for example, [RestartSec=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=) or [MemoryMax=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#MemoryMax=bytes) ) to a value, which is stored in file.

I know about [Environment=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) and [EnvironmentFile=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=), but, following documentation, they provide the ability to pass variable only to executing processes, but not to systemd.unit/systemd.service itself.

Comment: What is your actual goal and why not just edit the unit file using `systemctl edit <systemd-unit>`?

Comment: I'm creating instantiated service, i.e. example@.service . I will have external configuration files with parameters for every instance. Part of those parameters will be used by executed process itself (so I will use EnvironmentFile= for them), but other part is intented to be used by generated systemd service (for example, MemoryMax= which I mentioned in question above).

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to accomplish that. You could create drop-ins for the services with the configuration: `/etc/systemd/system/example@<instance-name>.service/override.conf`.

Comment: That's the result of my today's researches also, I'm just looking if I missed something. I appreciate your help, you can post the information from the last comment as a standalone answer, and, probably, I'll accept this answer as the best one.

Comment: I wouldn't know of a different method, since you always have to do a `systemctl daemon-reload` on unit changes. So I guess configuring units in a more dynamic way seems out of scope. Maybe someone else comes up with a solution...